# Excel VBA Userform: data overwrites when I change first column of data entry

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using the following code to enter data from Userform to Excel sheet and works fine. 
The problem is that it overwrites the same row of data. But if I change:
`.Cells(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.DepSectDrop.Value` to contain a 1 --> `.Cells(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.DepSectDrop.Value`, and likewise for the rest (2 fore SiteFacOpen, 3 for CaseStartOpen, etc), it does not overwrite.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("TRACK")
    RowCount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.DepSectDrop.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.SiteFacOpen.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.CaseStartOpen.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.TypeDrop.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.ProcessDrop.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.CompNameOpen.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 10).Value = Me.CompEIDOpen.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 11).Value = Me.RespNameOpen.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 12).Value = Me.RespEIDOpen.Value
        .Cells(RowCount, 13).Value = Me.DescOpen.Value

    End With
    'Clear input controls.
    Me.DepSectDrop.Value = ""
    Me.SiteFacOpen.Value = ""
    Me.CaseStartOpen.Value = ""
    Me.TypeDrop.Value = ""
    Me.ProcessDrop.Value = ""
    Me.CompNameOpen.Value = ""
    Me.CompEIDOpen.Value = ""
    Me.RespNameOpen.Value = ""
    Me.RespEIDOpen.Value = ""
    Me.DescOpen.Value = ""

End Sub
```

What do I need to do to so I maintain the right columns for it all to be entered, but not be overwritten? Thank you

Comment: I think your row count is looking for the last row with the 1st column. Assuming there is nothing in column 1 it keeps starting from the same row? Maybe change your `RowCount` to `ws.Cells (Rows.Count, 4).End (xlUp).Offset (1,0).Row` see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change all lines that start

```
     .Cells(RowCount, 5).Value ...
```

To

```
     .Cells(RowCount + 1, 5).Value
```

The '+1' bit means you're using the next blank line.

Also, as Samuel pointed out, you should also change to

```
 RowCount = ws.Cells (Rows.Count, 4).End (xlUp).Offset (1,0).Row
```

so that you're testing a column that's guaranteed to have data in it!

---

Sorry, I missed the offset bit ... No need to '+1' if you're offsetting by 1 ... It amounts to the same thing.